# How to automatically uninstall a module before running a Nightwatch test?

Tags: 8, testing

I'm able to run Nightwatch without any problem but I would like to uninstall the Recaptcha module before running my test since the Recaptcha is preventing me from autosubmitting without passing the test.

I'm importing my DB in the `phpunit.xml` file in the core directory.

May be there are some hooks I could use?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the Node `exec` command to call drush like this:

```
module.exports = {
  '@tags': ['picostat'],
  before: function(browser) {
    const { exec } = require("child_process");
    exec("drush pmu recaptcha")
  },
  'Check a dataset was likely created correctly.': (browser) => {
    browser
      .drupalRelativeURL('/node/add/dataset')
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 2000)
      .assert.containsText('body', 'Create Dataset')
      .setValue('#edit-title-0-value', 'Test Dataset')
      .click('#edit-field-dataset-input-method-file')
      .click('#edit-field-dataset-header-false')
      .setValue('input[name="body[0][value]"]', 'Test dataset body')
      .end();
  }
};
```